# OpenFileDialog to show files in Isolated Storage directory

Tags: winforms, isolatedstorage, openfiledialog

This is a dotnet 4.5 winforms program (full trust).

I have a number of files stored in a directory in isolated storage (FormatFiles).

I would like to use the OpenFileDialog to allow the user to select one of these files and once that is solved use SaveFileDialog to allow them to name a file to be saved there.

Can I point the dialogs to this directory in isolated storage? If so, sample code.

Comment: You cannot find out where the files are stored.  So, no.

Comment: I don't need/want to know where the files are stored, just want to use the "standard" way to let the user select one of them. I guess you are saying that the dialog does need to know via it's initial directory property